# Wrapping <a href=" around inputted form data

Tags: html, forms, input, hyperlink, contact-form

I'm making a PHP contact form that a user inputs a url e.g: 'www.google.com'. On submit, I need the address to be wrapped into a href attribute. So its stored into my database as: <@ href="www.google.com">Visit Site<|a>

I have tried using multiple hidden inputs and and escape chars, but obviously the formatting doesn't allow the value to be entered correctly so I've tried using special chars and most likely leaves it open for spoofing.

```
     <div class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="URL[]" value="&lt;a href=&quot;&gt;"> <!--<a href="-->
                  <label for="URL">URL link</label>      
                  <input type="url" class="form-control" id="URL" name="URL[]" value-hidden="https">
                  <input type="hidden" name="URL[]" value="&quot;&lt;&sol;a&gt;"> <!--"</a>-->
                </div>
```

Is there a way? Perhaps using JQuery or should I consider implementing this in my post method? Thanks!

Comment: "On submit, I need the address to be wrapped into a href attribute." — No. You don't. Since you sometimes need to use the data **without** that transformation, doing it when you insert it into the database is actively harmful. Do the transformation when you pull the data from the DB and generate the HTML that needs that transformation.

Comment: I'd recommend not storing html in your database. Just store the link and inject it after retrieval e.g. using JQuery like you already considered.

Comment: Dope! Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you.